# developer products for Google Meet

Tags: google-apps-script, button, video, google-api, google-meet

<hello world!>
(I always wanted to do it)
Folks, I want to add a button on Google Meet, since I'm a one-man business, I teach private language classes I want to be able to change the Call's background on the go.
I don't know if Elgato Stream deck does this, yet I'm not ready to pay just to try.
Yeah Yeah I know about OBS, but my chromakey isn't as good as Google Meet's AI.

Thank you.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Can you provide more information about what exactly you need? If what you need is related to a Feature Requests inside Google Meets you can submit it via the `Feedback` button. It would be nice if you could review the [how to ask guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), it would help to better understand your question.